# PT_LOAD issue when trying to call ld

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, ld, riscv

I'm trying to build a riscv elf binary. To do so I'm using :

- app.ld
- kernel.ld
- ldscript.ld
- user.s
- reset.s
- exception.s
- test.s

Basically what I am doing is building .o files ie user.o, reset.o and exception.o using the app.ld script for the users files and kernel.ld for the priviledge files.
Here's a look at the ldscript :
app.ld :

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )

SECTIONS
{
   . = seg_user;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .tohost : { *(.tohost) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .data.string : { *(.data.string)}
   .bss : { *(.bss) }
   _app_end = .;
}
```

kernel.ld :

```
OUTPUT_ARCH( "riscv" )

SECTIONS
{
   . = seg_reset;
   .reset : { *(.reset) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .kernel : { *(.kernel) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .exit   : { *(.exit) }
   _kernel_end = .;
}
```

ldscript.ld :

```
seg_reset   = 0xBFC00000;
seg_user    = 0x80000000;
ENTRY(_reset)


SECTIONS
{
   . = seg_reset;
   .reset : { *(.reset) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .kernel : { *(.kernel) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .exit   : { *(.exit) }

   . = seg_user;
   .text         : { *(.text) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .tohost       : { *(.tohost) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .data         : { *(.data) }
   .data.string  : { *(.data.string)}
   .bss          : { *(.bss) }
   _end = .;

}
```

To build it I'm using a makefile :

```
#---------------------------------------
# Building programm
#---------------------------------------

build_sw: build_dir kernel_obj user_obj
    $(RISCV) -nostdlib -march=rv32im -T sw/ldscript/ldscript.ld obj_dir/reset.o obj_dir/exception.o obj_dir/exit.o $(TEST)

kernel_obj: build_dir $(patsubst $(SW_DIR)/kernel/%.s,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SW_DIR)/kernel/*.s))

user_obj  : build_dir $(patsubst $(SW_DIR)/user/%.s,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SW_DIR)/user/*.s))

build_dir :
    mkdir -p $(ODIR)

# build kernel
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SW_DIR)/kernel/%.s $(LD_DIR)/kernel.ld
    $(RISCV) $(RISC_FLAGS) -T $(LD_DIR)/kernel.ld $< -c -o $@

# build user
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SW_DIR)/user/%.s $(LD_DIR)/app.ld
    $(RISCV) $(RISC_FLAGS) -T $(LD_DIR)/app.ld $< -c -o $@
```

The thing is I need the sections reset, kernel..etc to be in the Program Headers, right now if I run readelf -l on my executable I got :

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0xbfc00000
There are 2 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x001000 0x80000000 0x80000000 0x00044 0x00044 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x80001000 0x80001000 0x00078 0x00078 RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .tohost
```

I've read some stuff about PHDRS but when I try to add this in my ldscript.ld :

```
seg_reset   = 0xBFC00000;
seg_user    = 0x80000000;
ENTRY(_reset)

PHDRS
{
   reset PT_LOAD ;
   kernel PT_LOAD ;
   exit PT_LOAD;
   text PT_LOAD ;
   data PT_NULL ;
   data.string PT_NULL ;
   bss PT_NULL ;
}

SECTIONS
{
   . = seg_reset;
   .reset : { *(.reset) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .kernel : { *(.kernel) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .exit   : { *(.exit) }

   . = seg_user;
   .text         : { *(.text) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .tohost       : { *(.tohost) }
   . = ALIGN(0x1000);
   .data         : { *(.data) }
   .data.string  : { *(.data.string)}
   .bss          : { *(.bss) }
   _end = .;

}
```

I got the following error :  no sections assigned to phdrs
And i have no idea what it means, any help would be welcomed